# EXCEL - How do I find a cell with specific content, and then reference that CELL (not its content) in another formula? (example within)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, countif

Ideally, I'd like to not delve into VBA with this, cuz I already am not the greatest with EXCEL.  Here's my situation, and thank you in advance to anyone who can help!...

Each cell in Row 1 of a sheet called "workload" is an ascending date.  So, A1 = 1/1/2016 - B1 = 1/2/2016 - C1 = 1/3/2016, etc...

Elsewhere in another sheet called "legend", I have this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(workload!$A$2:$AE$66,"some text string")
```

There are 65 rows of actual non-header data in "workload" (rows 2-66).  This formula looks for all instances of "some text string" in any of the cells from A2-AE66 (all of my non-header data).  This, in effect, gives me a "date range" (based on the headers in Row 1 described above) of 1/1/2016-1/31/2016 (31 columns traversed...31 days in that date range).

What I want to do is have two other cells somewhere that I can enter a START DATE and an END DATE.  So, what I am looking for is a way to make my COUNTIF formula read like:

```
=COUNTIF(workload!$START_DATE_COLUMN$2:$END_DATE_COLUMN$66,"some text string")
```

If that is wholly confusing, a practical example would yield the effect of the following, if I entered "1/2/2016" into my START DATE cell and "1/15/2016" into my END DATE CELL:

```
=COUNTIF(workload!$B$2:$O$66,"some text string")
```

(because Column B has a value of "1/2/2016" in its header row [B2] and Column O has a value of "1/15/2016" in its header row [O2])

I hope that all made sense, and is possible!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me, FYI:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'workload'!"&ADDRESS(1,MATCH(legend!A1,workload!1:1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(66,MATCH(legend!A2,workload!1:1,0))),"Red")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the range with a couple of [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pairs.

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(workload!A:ZZ, 2, MATCH(START_DATE_COLUMN, workload!1:1, 0)):
         INDEX(workload!A:ZZ, MATCH("zzz", workload!A:A), MATCH(END_DATE_COLUMN, workload!1:1, 0)),
        "some text")
```

The above assumes that you have created named ranges (e.g. START_DATE_COLUMN and END_DATE_COLUMN)

Comment: I actually do not at all know what that is/means.  Is that an easy concept?  I'll google around.  Thanks!

Comment: @MHoff In short: MATCH looks at a 1 dimensional array [a row or column] and tells you the number of elements in that a match was found [or an error if no match was found]. ie: in a list of the alphabet shown in column A, MATCH("D",A:A,0) would provide the result "4", because D was found in the 4th row. INDEX is basically the opposite - give it an array and an element number, and it will return that element. ie: INDEX(A:A,4) returns the result "D" in our example. You can thus split these into different cells, or combine like INDEX(B:B,MATCH("D",A:A,0))), to give the col B value where col A ="D"